# Chaining HTTP post promises angular not in sequence

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand of using of '.then' to chain promises, but the application that I am creating still does not fire in sequence.

```
dataFactory.getFirst().then(function(resp3){
       //handling of resp
        console.log('one');

    }).then(dataFactory.doSecond(val).then(function(resp) {
       //handling of resp
        console.log("two");

    })).then(dataFactory.getThird().then(function(resp2) {
        //handling of resp
        console.log("three");

    })).then(function(){
      $state.go('tab.main'); //goes to main page
    });
```

'dataFactory.' are all my HTTP Post methods invoked in my services.js. I do understand I did not include any exception/failure handling as I re-coded my whole codes(non-promise) to this from scratch. I will add them in once I fixed this problem.

The problem is sometimes, 'getThird()' values will be printed on the console first followed by 'doSecond()'values , which is something that I do not want. Any guidance and suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

**Update: Even taking '@Jaromanda X' answers into consideration I'm still unable to achieve sequential chaining. The console is not printing 'one, two, three' in sequence. Is it due to the server response delay?**

Updated Code:

```
var resp; var resp2; var resp3;

(resp3 =dataFactory.getFirst(valone))
.then(function(resp3){
    console.log('one');
})
.then(resp = dataFactory.doSecond(val))
.then(function(resp) {
    //handling of resp
    console.log("two");
})
.then(resp2 = dataFactory.getThird(valtwo))
.then(function(resp2) {
    //handling of resp
    console.log("three");
}).then(function(){
    $state.go('tab.main'); //goes to main page
});
```

doSecond(val) all functions are similar to this , just different address and different values returned:

```
dataFactory.doSecond= function(val){
    var config = {
        headers:  {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }

var data = 'val=' + val;
var httpAddressdoSecond = "http://"+IPAddress+"/webserviceURL";

return $http.post(httpAddressdoSecond, data, config);

};
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do this

```
dataFactory.getFirst()
.then(function(resp3){
    console.log('one');
})
.then(dataFactory.doSecond)
.then(function(resp) {
    //handling of resp
    console.log("two");
})
.then(dataFactory.getThird)
.then(function(resp2) {
    //handling of resp
    console.log("three");
}).then(function(){
    $state.go('tab.main'); //goes to main page
});
```

Because the way you're doing it, you're invoking doSecond, getThird immediately, rather as a result of the previous promise resolving

Comment: My 'resp' becomes undefined after following your method, any ideas?

Comment: without seeing what `doSecond` and `getThird` functions are, no chance - my guess is that `doSecond` doesn't actually return anything. Your original code did nothing with resp, so no clue